# Gentiles, what happens if they break the 7 laws

Tags: gentiles

What happens to gentiles if they break the 7 laws.

Comment: Welcome here! Interesting question. The Rambam [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.8.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) writes that one observing the seven laws in specific circumstances gains a portion of the World to come. So not observing would not allow that. Luckily one can always do *tshuva* (repentance) on one's shortcomings. Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 2):

> 'Even though the Talmud and Maimonides stipulate that a non-Jew who violated the Noachide laws was liable to capital punishment, contemporary authorities have expressed the view that this is only the maximal punishment. According to this view, there is a difference between Noachide law and halakhah. According to halakhah, when a Jew was liable for capital punishment it was a mandatory punishment, provided that all conditions had been met, whereas in Noachide law death is the maximal punishment, to be enforced only in exceptional cases.'

-- 'Jewish Concepts: The Seven Noachide Laws' [@Jewish Virtual Library](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/the-seven-noachide-laws)

Noachide Laws were collected with their explanation in Maimonides' Sefer Shoftim ("Book of Judges") in the last section Hilchot Melachim U’Milchamot ("The Laws of Kings and Wars") chapters [8:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188353/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-8.htm)-[9](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188354/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-9.htm)-[10:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188355/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-10.htm). For the teaching of the Talmud and the 3 laws that were liable to capital punishment, see  Babylonian Talmud, Sanhedrin 57a.

Comment: Well done. Hilchot Melachim is part of Mishne Torah so I removed the "see also". The gemara is in Sanhedrin 56a (top of page and from bottom). I already upvoted, can't do it twice :->